# Apply custom order to one level in a pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame that is the rolling covariance of some time-series.
I have no control over how it's made, it's given to me.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ["2019", "2020"]
order = ["first", "second", "last"]

covariance = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(len(order), len(order))), columns=order, index=order)
    for _ in dates], keys=dates, axis="index"
).sort_index(axis="index").sort_index(axis="columns")

print(covariance)
#                 first      last    second
# 2019 first   0.924892  0.785106  0.183837
#      last    0.669871  0.396943  0.859806
#      second  0.125323  0.365780  0.001017
# 2020 first   0.062085  0.875674  0.204438
#      last    0.218133  0.685526  0.313454
#      second  0.490463  0.823525  0.315452
```

**Goal:** to apply my custom order for the second level of index.

I have found a *hacky* way but it is quite ugly:

```
dates = covariance.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique()
covariance_ordered = pd.concat([
    covariance.loc[date].loc[order, order]
    for date in dates], keys=dates, axis="index"
)

print(covariance_ordered)
#                 first    second      last
# 2019 first   0.924892  0.183837  0.785106
#      second  0.125323  0.001017  0.365780
#      last    0.669871  0.859806  0.396943
# 2020 first   0.062085  0.204438  0.875674
#      second  0.490463  0.315452  0.823525
#      last    0.218133  0.313454  0.685526
```

Do you know better solutions?

Comment: Make your second level an ordered [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) and you'll be able to use any custom order.